# Transfer Learning and Recommender Systems

Tags: machine-learning, recommender-system, transfer-learning

I have a task in which I am pretending to have an "unobserved" system, let's call it the target system, that I am using an LSTM from a similar system that has observations to perform the regression. I call these observed systems the source systems.

However, to find the most similar source systems to use I must use some metadata about the systems that are available even for the unobserved targets. The idea is that we can find similarities in the metadata to indicate which source systems will perform well.

To do this I assume I need to create some kind of similarity or distance function on the metadata. Since I don't have too many source systems (about 70), I'm guessing the algorithm must be simple. I'm thinking linear regression on the differences in metadata between the source and the target. If so, how would you define a similarity function based on this regression? Is regression even the best way to go about this?

I'm not too knowledgeable about recommender systems but would this be a case where we would want to "recommend" a source system?

If there are resources about these kinds of problems available please let me know as well, I can't seem to find much in the few transfer learning survey papers I have read.